# Can I add a custom block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to have a block with 3 text body fields. I've done this before in Drupal 8 where I created a custom block and was able to add different fields to it.

In my Drupal 7 setup, I can add a block but cannot see where to add a custom block. Is this possible? If not, is there a way to set up a block with 3 different body fields?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Bean module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean), this will allow you to create custom Block types with fields, even image fields. It integrates nicely with the blocks module.